iOS Simulator Fails to Launch .app File Built with xcodebuild
I'm creating a build to use in UI automation with the following xcodebuild command:
xcodebuild -scheme Test-QA \
        -project $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/iosApp/Test.xcodeproj \
        -sdk iphonesimulator \
        -configuration 'Debug QA' \
        -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15,OS=latest' \
        -derivedDataPath "/Users/test/build" \
        clean build

Installed the app using 'xcrun simctl install booted /path/appfile.app'
Works fine on the original machine's simulator. However, when I try to run the .app file on the testing machine's simulator, it returns the following error:
    xcrun simctl launch booted com.test.app.qa
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
Simulator device failed to launch com.test.app.qa.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
    The request to open "com.test.app.qa" failed.
    The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).

Additional Details:
Both machines are running the same version of Xcode and arm64.
The simulator was reset to ensure a clean state.
The same error persists even after rebooting the machines.
Ensured that the bundle identifier is correct. Both devices have Rosetta installed.
What could be causing this error?

Enable verbose logging to get more detailed output
xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level=debug --style=syslog
